# AVPlayer not working correct w/ my array - swift

Tags: sorting, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have  UI Collection that retrieves data from your camera roll to load all your videos into the collection. Now what I am attempting to do is when you select a video in the collection, to play it in my custom UIView that is an AVPlayer; everything works great, except that when I play the video it does not always play the correct video in array I have appended the video urls in to. It will usually just play a random video from the library and sometimes crash the app pointing to where I am appending the video urls and saying "fatal out of range". I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring. It is correctly printing out the values of the array as well as the count; so I think it has to do with how I am retrieving the video.

Here is where I am fetching the video:

```
 let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions) {
    if fetchResult.count > 0 {
        for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

            //Used for fetch Image//
            imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                image, error in
                let imageOfVideo = image! as UIImage
                self.imageArray.append(imageOfVideo)
            })
            //Used for fetch Video//
            imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {(avAsset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                if let asset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let videoData = NSURL(string: "\(asset.url)")
                    let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
                    let durationInSecond = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                    print(durationInSecond)
                    self.videoArray.append(videoData!)
                    print(self.videoArray)
                }

            })
        }

    }
    else{
        //showAllertToImportImage()//A function to show alert
    }
}
}
```

The loading of each cell -> I don't think this matter though

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! VideoSelectionCVCell

    cell.uploadedFile.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

The didSelect: ->> I think this is where the issue is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    displayView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2, width:self.view.frame.size.width / 1.15, height: self.view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
    displayView.center = view.center
    displayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    displayView.layer.cornerRadius = displayView.layer.frame.size.width / 10
    displayView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    displayView.layer.borderWidth = 4
    //displayView.avPlayerLayer.cornerRadius = displayView.avPlayerLayer.frame.size.width/10
    displayView.url = videoArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

The count

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}
```

The custom player:

```
class VideoPlayBack: UIView {

var url: NSURL!
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var cancelButton: UIButton!

// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url! as URL)
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer.currentItem)


    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    //avPlayerLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
    avPlayer.play()


}

func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
    let playerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    playerItem.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}
}
```

Here is the full collection view class just in case.

https://paste.ee/p/JgZSu

Again, I think it has to do with how I am appending and retrieving the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having 2 arrays, I believe it would be much safer to create a small class or struct (i.e. Media) to hold the image and the video and create a Media array to use for your collection view. This is because the 2 methods for fetching are asynchronous so you never know really what index which video/image combo will be assigned to. Also, try nesting the async calls so that the same media instance is used for both calls to keep data consistency.

Here is a non tested example:

```
struct Media {
    var image:UIImage?
    var videoURL:URL?
}

var mediaArray = [Media]()

for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
    let mediaItem = Media()
    //Used for fetch Image//
    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
        image, error in
        let imageOfVideo = image! as UIImage
        mediaItem.image = imageOfVideo;
        //Used for fetch Video//
        imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {(avAsset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
            if let asset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                let videoData = URL(string: "\(asset.url)")
                let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
                let durationInSecond = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                print(durationInSecond)
                mediaItem.videoURL = videoData!
                self.mediaArray.append(mediaItem)
            }

        })
    })
}
```

Then use the media array to populate your collectionView. don't forget to always unwrap the data. Don't use force unwrapping and you will (almost) never have crashes